# Angularjs apply directive/jquery after ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, angularjs

this has been doing my head in...

**After my app dynamically inserts html content, I can't find a way to allow jquery to interact with it, or allow angularjs to apply directives over it.** I suspect the answers (to both issues) are closely related so I have posted them as one.

I suspect that I need to $apply() or $compile() on the dynamic html content (inserted through ajax). However, I can't seem to figure how to do that, tried with filters but that didn't work because scope is inaccessible to the filter.

I'm actually pretty surprised--angularjs is very thorough framework and I would expect this sort of situation is a very common and as such would either have built in support, or at very least have some sort of built in filer/function that handles this--perhaps it exists, and I've just missed it.

Your input is appreciated

**Here is a link with the code that illustrates this problem:** 
[CODE](http://plnkr.co/edit/qPFft0TBZT1QvaalzUjj?p=preview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have a few options depending on what you're ultimately trying to do.

If you simply want to "partial" content from an external source you can use `ng-include`.\

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude

If however you need to do something with that content and somehow manually control the inclusion of the content you could use `$compile` as you mentioned earlier.  Here's a fork of the code you posted up that demonstrates this approach.

http://plnkr.co/edit/534P199uu7hDlMoIkeka

Hopefully that helps.  If not feel free to leave a comment and I'll try to help you out more.

Comment: Perfect! many many thanks--didn't think of using a directive to channel that dynamic content and compile it :) this directive business is pretty powerful